# Jmeter: Running the nongui command using java

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run the `jmeter nongui` command using java as follows:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\apache-jmeter-2.13\\bin\\jmeter.bat -t \"C:\\jmeter scripts\\test.jmx\" -n -l \"C:\\jmeter scripts\\nonGUI.csv\"");
```

It runs perfectly fine, until I add the argument: 
`-Jusers=15` inside the command mentioned above in the next run.

The property set for the number of threads is: `${__P(users,10)}`

The result file does not seem to fill up and the process seems to run forever under the CPU Resource monitor.

**P.S.**: Please do not suggest me to run the jmeter file using the steps given in the blazemeter website. It has used one of the deprecated method and there is no resolution given for the plausible runtime errors in that website.

Comment: Did the jmeter log file show any errors or help point at the issue?

Comment: what error do you get ? show jmeter.log please, can you also show the full code when it breaks?

Comment: there is no error. The process id in the network resource monitor runs for some time and then it goes off. But the CPU resource monitor still shows the same process id with the status running.

Comment: Can you run it correctly from the command line (without Java)? Just to narrow down the possible sources of troubles. Where did you put the -Jusers=15 in the command?

Comment: @vernjan, yes i am able to. The above problem is resolved. See my answer below. I have another issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce your error, but here is a complete example with JMX File.  I removed the need for the "".

```
  // OSX exmaple  
  public class r {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec("/usr/local/bin/jmeter -t /Users/rfriedman/jmeter/SimpleUrl.jmx -Jusers=15 -n -l /Users/rfriedman/jmeter/nonGUI.csv");
      }
    }
```

Just to make sure I ran modified on Windows as well

```
// Windows Example
public class r {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\Users\\rfriedman\\Desktop\\apache-jmeter-2.13\\bin\\jmeter.bat -t C:\\Users\\rfriedman\\Desktop\\SimpleUrl.jmx -Jusers=20 -n -l C:\\Users\\rfriedman\\Desktop\\nonGUI.csv");  
        }
    }
```

[JMeter Test Plan](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/16631)

Comment: Hi Richard, it breaks for the user only if he adds -Jusers=10

Comment: Sorry I posted the code without the -J but i tested both. Thanks for the catch - updating the example

Comment: Actually the windows example does have -Jusers=20

Comment: Oups , sorry missed it :-) I upvoted then your answer

Comment: It works after I add the property value for Synchronization timer. Also, if I have to pass the value of -Jusers in the form of variable, how to do it? eg:

Answer (score 0):

It works after I add the property value for Synchronization timer similar to Thread count.

Also, if I have to pass the value of -Jusers in the form of variable, how to do it? I am trying to do the following. But it's not getting executed. 
eg: 
int value=10; 
Process pr = rt.exec("C:\Users\rfriedman\Desktop\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\jmeter.bat -t C:\Users\rfriedman\Desktop\SimpleUrl.jmx -Jusers=value -n -l C:\Users\rfriedman\Desktop\nonGUI.csv");

**Update:**

I tried with String value="10"; as well. Still the jmeter logs says:

"jmeter.reporters.Summariser: summary =      0 in     0s = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)"

Comment: Are you trying to pass in from the command line?  java RunMyTest 50

Comment: @RichardFriedman, no. I am using eclipse and the java program has the above snippet. Can you please tell me how to pass the variable in place of value in the following code?     It's not working. int value=2;
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\apache-jmeter-2.13\\bin\\jmeter.bat  -t \"C:\\jmeter scripts\\test.jmx\" -Jusers=value -Jsync=value -n -l \"C:\\jmeter scripts\\nonGUI.csv\" -j \"C:\\jmeter scripts\\jmeterLogs.log\"");

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet.

```
int value = 10;
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\apache-jmeter-2.13\\bin\\jmeter.bat" +
            " -t \"C:\\jmeter scripts\\test.jmx\" -Jusers=" + value + " -Jsync=" + value + 
            " -n -l \"C:\\jmeter scripts\\nonGUI.csv\" -j \"C:\\jmeter scripts\\jmeterLogs.log\"");
```